# Cannot bind result of HTTPUtility method to session variables

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, webforms, session-variables, httputility

I am using ASP.NET Web Forms. I am trying to bind some data from a previous page (including the URL and some specific figures stored in the URL) to session variables for use in a SQL insert statement to a SQL Server database.

An example of one of the assignments is below:

```
this.Session["URL"] = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.UrlReferrer.Query)["helpurl"];
```

The problem I am having is that on executing the SQL insert, the value does not seem to be present and the default value is recorded. SessionState is enabled. I am able to print the result of the HttpUtility method to a label, and I am also able to assign to session variables for a SQL statement if I assign them directly, eg:

```
this.session["Variable"] = Variable;
```

Any ideas why the result of the HttpUtility function may not be assigned to the session variable prior to the execution of the SQL insert statement?

Comment: The code seems to be correct `this` keyword is not necessary. You can put your full code then some one can help.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok - I placed the assignments inside an

```
if(!IsPostBack)
```

And they now work ok and are being recorded to the database. I also removed the 'this' keyword from them.

Thanks anyway